# Is there any reason for me to to setup a DFS Namespace and shares if I want to use DFS-R to keep 2 folders in sync?

Tags: windows-server-2012, dfs-r

I am using DFS-R to keep 2 folders in sync.  If I do not need a single share path for these folders, is there any reason or advantage for me to setup a DFS Namespace as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do setup a DFS namespace share, when users write to the share, which actual server will the files be initially written to?

DFS clients use same information to detect the proper member that is used for looking up the closest Domain Controller.  It grabs information you have defined in AD Sites and services and hopefully a client will be identify its own site, and the sites of the DFS server.  It then tries to use a DFS member from the local site.

> is there any reason or advantage for me to setup a DFS Namespace as well

Not really.